# What is a functional infrastructure required to run a Bitcoin blockchain?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

I need to understand what type of functional infrastructure required to run a Bitcoin. I found following article on the topic but I'm still not clear what is a "functional infrastructure" for bitcoin. I would appreciate an easy to understand explanation.

https://imiblockchain.com/blockchain-infrastructure-requirements/

Answer (score 0):

> What is a functional infrastructure required to run a Bitcoin blockchain?

To run the whole Bitcoin blockchain:

- A bunch of participants, each with

  - A computer device
  - Internet access
  - Bitcoin application software (e.g. Bitcoin Core)
  - Sufficient storage
- Several participants with mining hardware and software.

To Participate

- Any device for which there exists a Bitcoin wallet application